# Which BAdI/user-exit triggers for tax code MWSKZ?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, badi

​Hello,

A tax code **MWSKZ** is being modified while generation of the accounting document,

it is displayed fine in FB01, but after the generation of the accounting document, I leave to FB03 and I find that the value of tax code is modified (FB03).

Example : in FB01 i entered A0 as tax Code and i save, in FB03 i find it changed to AA

I checked :

1. AC_Document
2. ACC_Document
3. EXIT_SAPLV60A_001
4. EXIT_SAPLV60B_008
5. substitutions

is there any other BADi or User exIt that change the value of **MWSKZ** in **BSEG** table.

Answer (score 3):

There are few places where you can check,

1. BADI_ACC_DOCUMENT, it can be implemented you can check it from
   se18.
2. User-exit ACBAPI01, SMOD or CMOD.
3. This one is a little tricker, I guess. It can be defined in Validation of 
   accounting document - OB28, or other OKC7, OKC9 etc. It can be changed in 
   Exit, probably.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Oguz, 
its really frustrating, the BAdI BADI_ACC_DOCUMENT is not implemented, I did not find the modification nor in ACBAPI01 nest in OB28, or OKCx, i think i must debug to find it.

Comment: You may use string search program which is RS_ABAP_SOURCE_SCAN. You should give the program name as Z* and LZ*, otherwise it will take too long. And you are going to search 'AA', I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Check also the tax code assignment in GL master record (FS00).